# Velocity / PhpStorm live template syntax

Tags: phpstorm, velocity

How would one create a path as such? Since the `\$`is an escape for the `$` symbol, need to keep the backslash and the `${variable}` together.

```
use App\Domain\Entities\${EntityName};
```

It's probably really simple however I cannot see any examples.

http://velocity.apache.org/

Comment: What is the context? You need to describe a bit bigger picture here.

Comment: @LazyOne detail added

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is not used in Live Templates -- only in File & Code Templates; but Live Templates can be used in File templates. This mentioning of both "templates" is confusing...

---

Anyway... considering the syntax `${EntityName}`.. it had to be File Template context.

For IDE to ask for `EntityName` parameter when creating such new file just use `\\$`. The final line will look like this:

```
use App\Domain\Entities\\${EntityName};
```

[image]

[image]